# How can I remove the excess slash from the middle of this table?

Tags: tables, math-mode, horizontal-alignment

I'm trying to remove the excess slash as you can see in the attached image. I don't know how to do it and I can't even find it. I just want to maintain the slashes at both sides of the table.

[image]

This is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fontenc}
\usepackage{lscape}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{center}
    Tabela 1: Comparação dos métodos aplicadas para encontrar a menor raíz positiva de (2).
\end{center}    
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline
 & Bissecção & Posição Falsa & Ponto Fixo & Newton & Secante \\ \hline
$\varphi$ ou $f'$ & ----- & ----- & $\varphi_{1}{(x)} = \sqrt{2x \cdot \cot{(x)} +1}$ & $f'(x)$ & ----- \\ \hline
Dados Iniciais: $x^{(0)}$ ou $[a,b]$ & $[1.2,1.4]$ & $[1.2,1.4]$ & $x^{(0)} = 1.3$ &  &  \\ \hline
Aproximação para a raíz $\~x$ & 1.306494 & 1.306542 & 1.306546 &  &  \\ \hline
Valor de $f$ na aproximação: $f(\~x)$ & 1.1095205219580073e-06 & 5.398573945658569e-06 & 7.973302321662157e-06 &  &  \\ \hline
Majorante do erro ou diferença \\ entre duas interações consecutivas &  &  &  &  &  \\DDD \hline
Número de Iterações & 11 & 3 & 51 &  &  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Comment: How or where is `\DDD` defined? And, have you redefined `\~` as `\hat`? Please advise.

Comment: @Teepeemm sorry to confuse it. It's a false cognate in my language, you're right!

Comment: Use `Majorante do erro ou diferença &&&&&\\ ` instead of `Majorante do erro ou diferença \\ ` Your table isn't completed at this line.

Comment: @wipet It works!! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Three examples how you can solve your problem:

- with use of the `makecell` package
- with use of the `tabularx` package, and
- with use of `tabularray` package

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell,
            tabularx, 
            tabularray}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}
\caption{Comparação dos métodos aplicadas para encontrar a menor raíz positiva de (2)}

with \verb+\tabular & \makecell+

\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    & Bissecção & Posição Falsa & Ponto Fixo & Newton & Secante \\
    \hline
$\varphi$ ou $f'$
    & -----     & -----         & $\varphi_{1}{(x)} = \sqrt{2x \cdot \cot{(x)} +1}$
                                             &$f'(x)$ & ----- \\
    \hline
Dados Iniciais: $x^{(0)}$ ou $[a,b]$
    & $[1.2,1.4]$ & $[1.2,1.4]$ & $x^{(0)} = 1.3$ &  &  \\ \hline
Aproximação para a raíz $\tilde{x}$
    & 1.306494 & 1.306542 & 1.306546 &  &  \\ \hline
Valor de $f$ na aproximação: $f(\tilde{x})$
    & 1.1095205219580073e-06 & 5.398573945658569e-06 & 7.973302321662157e-06 &  &  \\ \hline
\makecell[l]{Majorante do erro ou diferença\\ entre duas interações consecutivas}
    &       &       &       &       &       \\
    \hline
Número de Iterações
    & 11    & 3     & 51    &       &       \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}


\medskip
with \verb+\tabularx+

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|X|c|c|c|c|c|} 
    \hline
    & Bissecção & Posição Falsa & Ponto Fixo & Newton & Secante \\ 
    \hline
$\varphi$ ou $f'$ 
    & -----     & -----         & $\varphi_{1}{(x)} = \sqrt{2x \cdot \cot{(x)} +1}$ 
                                             &$f'(x)$ & ----- \\ 
    \hline
Dados Iniciais: $x^{(0)}$ ou $[a,b]$ 
    & $[1.2,1.4]$ & $[1.2,1.4]$ & $x^{(0)} = 1.3$ &  &  \\ \hline
Aproximação para a raíz $\tilde{x}$ 
    & 1.306494 & 1.306542 & 1.306546 &  &  \\ \hline
Valor de $f$ na aproximação:  $\tilde{x}$
    & 1.1095205219580073e-06 & 5.398573945658569e-06 & 7.973302321662157e-06 &  &  \\ \hline
Majorante do erro ou diferença entre duas interações consecutivas 
    &       &       &       &       &       \\
    \hline
Número de Iterações 
    & 11    & 3     & 51    &       &       \\ 
    \hline
\end{tabularx}

\medskip
with \verb+\tabularray+

\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec = {X[j] *{5}{c}},
             }
    & Bissecção & Posição Falsa & Ponto Fixo & Newton & Secante \\
$\varphi$ ou $f'$
    & -----     & -----         & $\varphi_{1}{(x)} = \sqrt{2x \cdot \cot{(x)} +1}$
                                             &$f'(x)$ & -----   \\
Dados Iniciais: $x^{(0)}$ ou $[a,b]$
    & $[1.2,1.4]$   & $[1.2,1.4]$   & $x^{(0)} = 1.3$   &   &   \\  
Aproximação para a raíz $\tilde{x}$
    & 1.306494      & 1.306542      & 1.306546          &   &   \\  
Valor de $f$ na aproximação: $f(\tilde{x})$
    & 1.1095205219580073e-06 
                    & 5.398573945658569e-06 
                                    & 7.973302321662157e-06 
                                                        &   &   \\ 
Majorante do erro ou diferença entre duas interações consecutivas
    &               &               &                   &   &   \\
Número de Iterações
    & 11            & 3             & 51                &   &   \\
\end{tblr}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

[image]